# direct disk usage to different location for specific query (vacuum full), PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

When sending a query can I specify what disk space to use if I want to use a location that is different from the default?

So in this case, I want to do:

```
vacuum full tbl;
```

Instead of using the default disk space, can I specify a different location/tablespace?

So conceptually something like this:

```
vacuum full tbl 
send temp_files to tablespace x;
```

`tablespace x` points to some other location that has lots of extra space.

tablespaces:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html

For `vacuum full` haters, let's pretend it has to be done.

Comment: I think vacuum always uses the tablespace of the table. So if you want to do that, you need to move the table to a different tablespace

Comment: Using a different partition would mean making a copy of the vacuumed table to its final position rather than just renaming it. In other words, it would double the amount of writes, and you would still need the space for the vacuumed table in the location of the original one.

Comment: as soon as `SET TABLESPACE` only sends datafiles to a new location and `VACUUM FULL` only "rebuilds"table in place, it seems a nice feature to have - either with one or another, combining actions, so you would not have to do almost same job twice

Comment: @vaotsn - yes, I think just moving the table to a different tablespace did the trick for me by accidentally a question or two ago. Vacuum would be redundant at least in part